# Visual Studio Will Not Load Files from CLI

Tags: angular, visual-studio, angular-cli

I'm using the angular cli to generate components and services for my project however it will not load these files into the project.  For example, if I run this command -

```
ng g c my-test
```

it will create a folder called my-test, create four files inside of it, and update the parent module to include this new component.  However, the solution explorer doesn't show the folder or files.  I can right-click to add existing but that drills down to the file level and brings the files in up a level separate from the folder.

Comment: Are you using VS 2017, or something newer?

Comment: I am using VS 2022

Comment: I found that if I create the directory first in solution explorer the cli will use that folder and adding the files inside of it is more straight forward.